# A struct gets junk values ​when exiting a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The program should take a sentence and split it into individual words (homework),
The data is stored correctly to struct in "read_data" function(saw on debugger), after exiting to the main the members in the struct got junk values. what goes wrong? code is in c language.
thanks in advance.

```
//-----------------------------StructSection-------------------------------
struct Sentences
{
    char** _data;
    int _num_of_sentences;
};
//-----------------------------MainFunction------------------------------------
int main()
{
    struct Sentences sen; //structure storage
    char str[SIZE] = {0}; // string storage array

    read_data(sen,str); //call read data function
    copy_n_print_data(sen,str);
    free_data(sen); // call free memory function

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
//-----------------------------ReadDataFunction--------------------------------
void read_data(struct Sentences sen,char str[SIZE]) // main function
{
    int c;

    scanf("%d", &c);
    sen._num_of_sentences = c;

    sen._data = (char**) malloc (c * sizeof (char*));
    if(sen._data == NULL) //if not enough memory then call error function
        terminate();

    fgets(str, SIZE, stdin); //get string
    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", str);
}
```

Comment: You are passing the struct by value, not by reference. It is normal and expected that the struct remains uninitialized after `read_data`

Comment: If this is C++, you need to pass by reference. If it C, you need to pass by pointer. Which one are you using?

Comment: the code is in c, thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

Your `read_data` function takes arguments by value (copy). Changing the arguments (the copies) has no effect outside the function, so after the call you are just printing uninitialised variables (which is Undefined Behaviour btw).

What you *seem* to want is to take the arguments by *reference* (or pointer), so that your function can change the original variables passed in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `sen` you have in `read_data` is actually *not* the same one you have in `main` - it's just a copy. The one you have in `main` stays unchanged from its initial value - which indeed means it consists of junk values. A very simple way to fix this is to change `read_data` so that instead of taking `Sentences` as a value, have it create `Sentences` itself and return it - then `main` can just use what `read_data` returns. This'd look like this:

```
struct Sentences read_data(char str[SIZE]) // main function
{
    struct Sentences sen;
    int c;

    scanf("%d", &c);
    sen._num_of_sentences = c;

    sen._data = (char**) malloc (c * sizeof (char*));
    if(sen._data == NULL) //if not enough memory then call error function
        terminate();

    fgets(str, SIZE, stdin); //get string
    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", str);
    return sen;
}

int main()
{
    struct Sentences sen; //structure storage
    char str[SIZE] = {0}; // string storage array

    sen = read_data(str); //call read data function
    copy_n_print_data(sen,str);
    free_data(sen); // call free memory function

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Another thing you could do would be to pass it via pointer instead, making sure you *are* actually manipulating the same `struct Sentences` in both functions:

```
void read_data(struct Sentences* sen,char str[SIZE]) // main function
{
    int c;

    scanf("%d", &c);
    sen->_num_of_sentences = c;

    sen->_data = (char**) malloc (c * sizeof (char*));
    if(sen->_data == NULL) //if not enough memory then call error function
        terminate();

    fgets(str, SIZE, stdin); //get string
    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", str);
}
int main()
{
    struct Sentences sen; //structure storage
    char str[SIZE] = {0}; // string storage array

    read_data(&sen,str); //call read data function
    copy_n_print_data(sen,str);
    free_data(sen); // call free memory function

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```